# How to style a class (css) within a section with an attribute

Tags: css, attributes

I would like to style the `c-field` class. There is a padding of `8px` which I would like to remove.

HTML:

```
<div class="c-section c-col-1 c-sml-col-1 c-span-16 c-sml-span-12" data-field="UrenprognoseSamenstellenJaarrekening">
   <div class="">
      <div class="c-field c-col-1 c-sml-col-1 c-span-10 c-sml-span-12">
         <div class="c-editor c-html">
            <p>Jaarrekening, rapportage en dossier</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
.c-section[Data-Field="UrenprognoseSamenstellenJaarrekening"] > .c-field  {
padding:0px;}
```

Comment: You have no element with the class `c-field` that is a child of this element, so `>` is wrong.

Comment: Either remove the > or change CSS into *.c-section > div > .c-field* Bye the way, c-section sounds weird

Comment: @Gerard The last part of your comment made me chuckle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should try is removing the `>` selector and leave it as

```css
.c-section[Data-Field="UrenprognoseSamenstellenJaarrekening"] .c-field {
  padding: 0px;
}
```